# Kendo UI Template not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

We are trying to render some remote json data from AJAX to  Kendo UI template but without success.

```
<div id="example"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    function getCookie(key) {
      var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
      return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
    }
    var token = getCookie('_access_token');
    var userDS = null;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "url",            
      dataType: "json",
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
      success: function (data) {
        userDS = data;
        var template = kendo.template("<div>#= name #</div>");
        var data = JSON.stringify(userDS); 
        var result = template(data);
        $("#example").html(result); 
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });

  });
```

We are retriving the data without issue - it's tested with `console.log(data);` and the result is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Full Name",
    "username": "Username",
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "created_at": "2018-10-15 14:03:15",
    "updated_at": "2018-10-15 14:03:15"
}
```

Anyone can advice/help please?

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated because it freezes the browser. Move the code after your request inside the `success` function instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the information. I moved the code inside the success function but still is not working :/

Comment: Please post your updated code or update your question with the latest code.

Comment: i updated the main question, sorry. It continues to receiving data but is not rendering the KendoUI template/html

Comment: remove `var data = JSON.stringify(userDS);` (a good rule of thumb is to not use `JSON.stringify` unless you know what it does. Requesting JSON with jQuery returns on Object because jQuery already parses the response. So even if it didn't do that, you'd have to call JSON.parse() on it, not stringify.)

Comment: thank you very much. it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `JSON.stringify`? It turns your object into a string. Of course, the template engine cannot extract any values from it. Simply remove the line and you get your template.

Simplified working example:

```js
<div id="example"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Full Name",
        "username": "Username",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2018-10-15 14:03:15",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-15 14:03:15"
    };
    var template = kendo.template("<div>#= name #</div>");
    var result = template(data);
    $("#example").html(result); 
}); 
</script>
```